# MacOS PATH issue: which git I am using?

Tags: bash, git, macos, shell

On my macOS Catalina 10.15.5, I have two git installed, one is system default version in folder `/usr/bin`, one is install by brew in folder `/usr/local/bin`. The system $PATH env variable in as following, it is obvious `/usr/local/bin` is listed in front of `/usr/bin`. However, when I issue `git` on command line, the git in `/usr/bin` was executed, rather than the other one. How could this happen? The shell is bash.

```
lannis20mbp:~ lannis$ echo $PATH
/Users/lannis/anaconda3/bin:/Users/lannis/anaconda3/condabin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/bin
lannis20mbp:~ lannis$ which git
/usr/local/bin/git
lannis20mbp:~ lannis$ whereis git
/usr/bin/git
lannis20mbp:~ lannis$ git --version
git version 2.21.1 (Apple Git-122.3)
lannis20mbp:~ lannis$ /usr/bin/git --version
git version 2.21.1 (Apple Git-122.3)
lannis20mbp:~ lannis$ /usr/local/bin/git --version
git version 2.27.0
```

Comment: Try running `type git` rather than `which git`

Comment: try also the `alias` command to check if you have some alias set to `git`

Comment: @YusefMaali The command I suggested, `type git` will actually already tell you aliases and executables on your PATH that are hashed. Try it! :-)

Comment: @MarkSetchell amazing, thank you. I wasn't aware of it

Comment: @MarkSetchell it says `git is hashed (/usr/bin/git)`. what is hashed here? how to unhash it?

Comment: I tnink it's `hash -r`

Comment: Check with `help hash`

Comment: @MarkSetchell you're awesome, hash -r works. Now it gets back to normal. If you don't mind, would u pls put your comment in an answer and I will give it a check. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have added new binaries (executable programs) to your PATH since your shell started, you may need to rehash the lookup tables in your shell. You can do that with:

```
hash -r
```

---

If you want to know how the shell will interpret a given command, it is generally more useful to use `type COMMAND` rather than `which COMMAND` because `type` will also tell you if the command is aliased:

```
type git
```

Here is a simple example. First, see that `type find` and `which find` give the same result:

```
which find
/usr/bin/find

type find
find is /usr/bin/find
```

Next, create an alias for `find` which masks `/usr/bin/find`:

```
alias find='ls'
```

Now, see that `which` doesn't tell you what you want to know:

```
which find
/usr/bin/find
```

Whereas `type` does:

```
type find
find is aliased to `ls'
```

---

Read more about the `hash`, `type` and other builtins with:

```
help hash
help type
```

**Notes**: hash, rehash, type, builtin, builtins, built-in, built-ins, PATH, which.